# GCP Compute Engine with public on its NIC

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I have a Windows Server with a particular application which software license requires to detecte the NIC has the public IP address. Since CE instances assign just private IP address to the instances, and the public IP address is not visible from the instance on it's NIC, the license of this software application fails to register and recognize the server were this software is installed.

Is there any way I can assign a public IP address to the NIC of my CE instance and still being able to have GCP firewall between my CE instance and the public network?

I had this before on a traditional data center, where I had a Firewall Cisco between my Windows Server (with its public IP address) and the public network,

Thank you

Comment: what is software name ?

Comment: It is a voip softswitch application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not for GCP owned addresses, they manage that NAT.

Possibly you can bring your own IP addresses and Internet transit, [to make VMs with a custom IP addresses](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/custom-public-ip-addresses-on-compute-engine#creating_a_vm_with_a_custom_ip_address).

However, this is a crazy amount of work for a software licensing quirk. Complain to the vendor that this scheme does not work in cloud.

Comment: BYOIP addresses are managed by the Google Front End and cannot be directly assigned to a VM's NIC (network interface).

Comment: Also, BYOIP addresses can only be assigned to Google Cloud load balancers [link](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/bring-your-own-ip#open-ports)